# python split function error in "too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i am trying to figure out why i am getting the below error, i guess i get why i am getting the error but how do i make this work?

```
>>> port = '22-80'
>>> fromport, toport = port.split('-')
>>> fromport
'22'
>>> toport
'80'
>>> 
>>> # Here is the error
>>> 
>>> port = '-1--1'
>>> fromport, toport = port.split('-')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#192>", line 1, in <module>
    fromport, toport = port.split('-')
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> 
>>>
```

the output should be fromport should be -1 and toport should be -1 as well

Comment: what should the output be? You can use the maxsplit arg but there are multiple ways to interpret the output

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, how exactly are you planning to assign `['', '1', '', '1']` to just 2 variables? Either split only once by passing 1 to `split()` or in Python 3 you can also do `fromport, *toport = port.split('-')`.

Comment: voted to close as unless someone can mind read then what you actually want as output is  a guessing game

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print out `port.split('-')` you'll get `['', '1', '', '1']`. This is a list with 4 elements in it, and you're trying to unpack it into two variables:

```
fromport, toport = port.split('-')
```

The reason you're getting `['', '1', '', '1']` instead of `['1', '1']` is due to `str.split('-')` splitting the target string from both sides of every dash: Having two dashes next to each other will split the string from between them, resulting in an empty string (`''`).

You could remove all empty strings using list comprehension:

```
fromport, toport = [s for s in port.split('-') if s]
```